# Assigning anonymous method to delegate using parentheses gives compiler error?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

Given the following sample codes:

```
static void SomeMethod()
{
  Action<int,int> myDelegate;

  //...

  myDelegate = delegate { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); };
  myDelegate = delegate() { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); };  // compile error

}
```

What is the difference between

```
myDelegate = delegate { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); };
```

and

```
myDelegate = delegate() { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); };
```

?

In this example, the second statement generates compile error while the first one does not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An *anonymous method* has the syntax `delegate` *parameter-list* `{` *statement-list* `}`. The parameter list is optional.

If you *omit* the parameter list then the anonymous method is compatible with any delegate type where the parameters are not marked "out".

If you *supply* the parameter list then it must match the delegate parameter types exactly.

In your first case you are omitting it, and in the second case you are supplying it but not matching the delegate parameters. So `delegate {}` is legal, and `delegate (int i, int j) { }` is legal, but `delegate () {}` is not.

In any event, you are probably better off using a lambda expression; it is the more common syntax in new code:  `(i, j)=>{ }`;